# VB 2010 equivalent of Me.hWnd

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

What is the VB2010 mechanism for obtaining a form's handle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `Me.Handle`.

Comment: Well that was... obvious. Cheers.

Comment: Interestingly, I ignored that possibility because it wasn't suggested by the IDE. Given the exhausting list of members provided by VS, I would have assumed it was exhaustive. What is left off the list?